# MySQL LIKE Query changes in 5.1 to 5.6 to full table scan

Tags: mysql, django, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.1

For some reason MySQL 5.6 does a full table scan, while MySQL 5.1 doesn't. Why is this happening?

EDIT: Both tables have the same exact indices

On MySQL 5.1

```
    mysql> explain SELECT `kv`.`key`, `kv`.`value` FROM `kv` WHERE `kv`.`key` LIKE BINARY 'weit-149411-%';
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | kv           | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 192     | NULL |  182 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

On MySQL 5.6

```
    mysql> explain SELECT `kv`.`key`, `kv`.`value` FROM `kv` WHERE `kv`.`key` LIKE BINARY 'weit-149411-%';
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows        | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | kv           | ALL   | PRIMARY       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |  108364642  | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Do you have the same indices in both databases?

Comment: @schlonzo yup. just updated the question to add that.

Comment: Are the table definitions and contents otherwise identical?  What storage engine?

Comment: yup everything is identical. Its a read replica that I promoted. same number of rows, same definitions and everything. (sorry didnt post those)

Comment: Are your database character set and database collation the same as your table's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this is the intended effect. Starting in MySQL 5.5 `LIKE BINARY` no longer [uses available indexes](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=63563)

I am making a Django query that queries with `key__startswith` [1](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=63563) which does a BINARY query by default.

I was able to solve this issue by doing `key__istartswith` which does a [case insensitive query](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/507) on the key. This is fine for my use case since everything is lower case.

Answer (score 0):

The statistics you have on the 5.1 instance maybe stale and probably collected when the number of rows in that table was less.

Suggestion: on 5.6 , set global innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages=300; analyze table ; and check the query execution.